# npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree when installing @nest/microservices

Tags: node.js, npm, nestjs

I'm trying to install new dependency to my service,

```
@nest/microservices: ^7.0.3 and got this error:
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: vb-service-ads@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @nestjs/common@8.4.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@nestjs/common
npm ERR!   @nestjs/common@"^8.4.7" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @nestjs/common@"^7.0.0" from @nestjs/microservices@7.6.18
npm ERR! node_modules/@nestjs/microservices
npm ERR!   @nestjs/microservices@"^7.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
```

so versions of packages with problem are:

```
"@nestjs/common": "^8.4.7",
"@nestjs/core": "^7.6.15"
```

I tried to upgrade versions of core and microservices dependencies to ^8.0.0, and got more dependencies broken and also tried to downgrade common to ^7.6.15 and got same effect.
Tried to use yarn instead of npm, it resolved my problem, but i need all packages to be installed by npm

[image]

Comment: Please add the error as text and not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I resolved this problem, with deleting node_modules, package-lock.json and removing dependencies and devDependencies in package.json

After i've installed all dependencies manually one by one

Answer (score 0):

you can see the solution here, or at least this is what worked for me here. https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-in-angular-while-installing-npm-packages/

I leave you the part where it worked for me

> To fix Unable to resolve dependency tree error in Angular while
> installing npm packages follow the below steps.
>
> 1. Run `npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps` instead of `npm install` command. Another way is delete the `node_modules` folder and
>    package_lock.json file and then
> 2. Run `npm cache clean --force` after `npm i --force` command.

Comment: I am using nestjs and it gives me problems when installing @nestjs/microservice

Comment: thanks for your answer, I've needed to done it working with npm ci, so this method is not good for me.
Also i resolved my problem by deleting all dependencies and installing them one by one manually

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was that you used the wrong command:

```
npm i @nest/microservices
```

The correct could be this:

```
npm i @nestjs/microservices
```

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED:npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree when installing @nest/microservices**

```
$ npm install -g @nestjs/cli npm-check-updates
   $ nest update --force
    Open NestJs project
     $ npm-check-updates "/@nestjs*/" -u
     $ npm-check-updates "/nestjs*/" -u    
     $ npm install
```